# Joomla : how to create a Wrapper (iFrame) in tthe Backend Khepri Template

Tags: templates, iframe, joomla

Hello freinds I need help as to how can I add 2 iFrames in the Joomla's Default Back-end Template Khepri.

I want to show the Hosting cPanel and also another application's Control Panel in these iFrames.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to add a new module to the admin. Log in to your Joomla admin then select Extensions > Module Manager > Administrator.

This will get you to the modules manager for the administrative area. It works just like the front end. Click New module, then select Custom HTML and put your iFrame code in there.

Comment: Hmmm how stupid of me. Happens. Sometimes we go too deep forgetting the very basics. Thanks a lot for the help.